# Add CoreDataGeneratedAccessors to Existing Class

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have two existing `NSManagedObject` subclasses, and need added a new relationship between the two.

I tried adding manually adding the Relationships to the model (on both sides: one is 'to one' and the other is 'to many'). I then added the relevant method signatures in both header files. The one object is called `GameEvents` and the other is a `Player`.

In the GameEvents.h file:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) Player *player
- (void)addPlayerObject:(Player *)value;
- (void)removePlayerObject:(Player *)value;
```

and in the Player.h file

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *events;
- (void)addEventsObject:(GameEvents *)value;
- (void)removeEventsObject:(GameEvents *)value;
- (void)addEvents:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeEvents:(NSSet *)value;
```

The error that I get is the call to `[self addPlayerObject:p]` in GameObject.m source is an 'unrecognized selector.'

I reviewed the suggestions [Core Data - how to generate CoreDataGeneratedAccessors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9461659/core-data-how-to-generate-coredatageneratedaccessors) checking that the relations were properly defined, but the suggestion is to regenerate with `NSManagedObject`, but I have a bunch of custom code, so that's not possible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion best approach for this situation (having to add own code to the auto-generated NSManagedObject subclass) is the following:

1. Do not change the auto-generated files for NSManagedObject subclasses
2. Create in a separate file a class extension with your own code

This way, you can regenerate the auto-generated headers without overwriting your own code.

In your situation, I would recommend moving all of your own code into a class extension and then re-create the auto-generated file.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. I was coming to the same conclusion. My question is whether a category might be better. Seems like extensions would need to be in the @implementation file so they would be clobbered by the regeneration.

Answer (score 0):

I moved all of the non-generated code into a *classification*, regenerated the `NSManagedObject` classes, and successfully compiled and ran the application. I found an excellent overview of classifications and extensions [at this link](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/objective-c-succinctly-categories-and-extensions--mobile-22016)

One important note: **I had to delete the** `NSManagedObject` **classes, and then re-generate**. Otherwise, the classes were not replaced.